# Alternate for jet fuel

Tags: fuel, fuel-systems, propulsion

At some point maybe after around 8 to 10 decades we may end up with a situation where the crude oil wells get drained up due to massive extraction and increasing demand for gasoline and ATF. What would be the another option for the conventional fuel system?

Some of the prototypes like solar impulse, explorer etc. are for small light weight aircraft.  What about the massive aircraft like the Boeing 707,747 Airbus a380 and fighter jets.

My point is can't we make something like nuclear propelled aircraft? By designing some kind of miniature size of reactor or maybe any other way of non conventional propulsion system to over come the future oil crisis.

Comment: There has already been a nuclear powered aircraft, done 50 years ago or so.

Comment: How happy are you to sit inside a metal tube with a nuclear reactor?

Comment: Some bedtime reading for you all about alternate fuel sources in aviation linked for you :)

Comment: It is very technically straightforward (but energy intensive) to turn methane or coal into usable jet fuel. It will cost more than conventional fuels, but can be made in any desired quantity. Look at what the company Sasol has done in coal to liquids at large scale.